# Press Login Button Excel Vba

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I have the code below to login into the website in the code. However, the login button is not being clicked. I am new to Excel VBA, what do you suggest, please?

```
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer
Sub Myenter()

Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim MyURL As String
On Error GoTo Err_Clear
MyURL = "https://willemendrees.nl/fn/login/"
Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
MyBrowser.Silent = True
MyBrowser.navigate MyURL
MyBrowser.Visible = True
Do
Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.document
HTMLDoc.all.id_username.Value = "amsterdam@willemendrees.nl" 
HTMLDoc.all.id_password.Value = "*****" 
For Each MyHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
If MyHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next
End With
Err_Clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
Err.Clear
Resume Next
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `.Type`? That can't be right - you're probably looking for something like `.InnerHTML` instead, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a CSS [attribute = value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) selector of `[tabindex='3']`. This targets the login button by its `tabindex` attribute whose value is 3.

```
HTMLDoc.querySelector("[tabindex='3']").Click
```

Whole thing:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub AttemptLogin()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://willemendrees.nl/fn/login/"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            With .querySelector("#id_username")
                .Focus
                .Value = "amsterdam@willemendrees.nl"
            End With
            With .querySelector("#id_password")
                .Focus
                .Value = "***"
            End With
            .querySelector("[tabindex='3']").Click
        End With

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Stop '<== Delete me later
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are two form elements on that html page and the login is the second. Identify, then submit the form.

```
HTMLDoc.all.id_username.Value = "amsterdam@willemendrees.nl" 
HTMLDoc.all.id_password.Value = "*****" 
HTMLDoc.getelementsbytagname("form")(1).submit
```

The index number of a collection of elements is zero-based.